# CORS '*' doesn't seem to work for Chrome, it does for Postman

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I've created a custom middleware in Laravel for my project. It adds the following headers:

```
return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
```

The middleware seems to work fine for Postman. When I trigger a POST request via Postman, you'll notice the headers have been added to the response:
[image: header response POSTMAN]

However, for Chrome this doesn't seem to work. See the headers which have been returned from Google Chrome (same request, using axios for the calls):
[image: Chrome header response]

This results in the following error in the console of Google Chrome:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/jwt/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What am I doing wrong/is causing this odd issue?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and wilcarded origins are not compatible.

Comment: Postman is not subject to the same-origin policy and as such, does not need to issue pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests so your requests are definitely not the same

Comment: For me, the issue was that my VPN was on. Maybe you can check for such software(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating custom Laravel middleware, I'd highly recommend using the [Laravel CORS Package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It doesn't really explain why my solution didn't work since it should add the header to any type of request. Even Chrome's OPTION pre-flight request. I'll dig into the code of this Laravel CORS package to find out what I did wrong initially.

Answer (score 3):

Just put similar script on the very top of your file, with a die().

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])) {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "OPTIONS") {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");

        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Protection-Token");

        die();
    }
}
```

If you could translate into laravel, better. Implementation example is at [here](https://github.com/anytizer/api.php/blob/master/src/api-v1.php).

Answer (score 2):

i know that this post is a little old, now Laravel comes with an integrated cors solution at the config/cors.php file, but what keeps giving headaches regarding this, is that there is a line that says "paths"

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'];
```

This is the main problem, leave this value just like this:

```
'paths' => ['*'];
```

Or insert an array for every route in your API and your cors problem is gone!
Just to clarify, Cors is not a firewall, and postman does not send preflight or some other extra informations that chrome do.